# I have dns leak with openvpn in fedora 30

Tags: linux, dns, fedora, openvpn, dhcp

I've set up OpenVPN on Ubuntu server, And I'm running Fedora 30 at home, And I noticed that I have dns leak.

I have tried many solutions like the following :

---

solution(1) : Worked for a bit

New file:

```
nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

Then add:

```
supersede domain-name-servers <dns ip>;
```

Then restart network manger:

```
service NetworkManager restart
```

And then if I check in resolv.conf file to see if the dns being used or not:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

And it is being used but when I do dns leak test still there is a leak

---

solution(2) :

I have added this line to client.ovpn file, And nothing changed

```
setenv opt block-outside-dns
```

---

solution(3) :

And I tried these lines in client.ovpn file

```
script-security 2

up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf

down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Then I get this erorr:

```
'/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf': No such file or directory
```

---

All I need is to force the dns to go through the openvpn or to go through the dns I set.

Comment: If you installed OpenVPN from the Ubuntu repo, it should have installed the script `update-resolv-conf` and solution(3) should have worked after running `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn`.

Comment: @harrymc I couldn't find `update-resolv-conf` in `/etc/openvpn/` so I did create a new file, then I searched for update-resolv-conf content, then paste it to the file and it worked!. Thank you for guiding my to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem and here is how :

---

Add those lines to the end of client.ovpn

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Then try to connect:

```
openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

If you get this erorr:

```
'/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf': No such file or directory
```

Then do these extra steps:

```
nano /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Then paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 
# Adjusted for CentOS7/RHEL/Fedora
#
# Note: ideally networKManager would handle this via dnsmasq, but it doesn't
# appear to handle this dynamically as of yet.  So we'll just clobber it.
# We run the risk that NeworkManager will replace it later..
#
# Parses DHCP options from openvpn to update resolv.conf
# To use set as 'up' and 'down' script in your openvpn *.conf:
# up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
# down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
#
# Used snippets of resolvconf script by Thomas Hood and Chris Hanson.
# Licensed under the GNU GPL.  See /usr/share/common-licenses/GPL. 
# 
# Example envs set from openvpn:
#
#     foreign_option_1='dhcp-option DNS 193.43.27.132'
#     foreign_option_2='dhcp-option DNS 193.43.27.133'
#     foreign_option_3='dhcp-option DOMAIN be.bnc.ch'
#

split_into_parts()
{
    part1="$1"
    part2="$2"
    part3="$3"
}

case "$script_type" in
  up)
    NMSRVRS=""
    SRCHS=""
        for optionvarname in ${!foreign_option_*} ; do
        option="${!optionvarname}"
        echo "Found Option: $option"
        split_into_parts $option
        if [ "$part1" = "dhcp-option" ] ; then
            if [ "$part2" = "DNS" ] ; then
                NMSRVRS="${NMSRVRS:+$NMSRVRS }$part3"
            elif [ "$part2" = "DOMAIN" ] ; then
                SRCHS="${SRCHS:+$SRCHS }$part3"
            fi
        fi
    done
    R=""
    [ "$SRCHS" ] && R="search $SRCHS
"
    for NS in $NMSRVRS ; do
            R="${R}nameserver $NS
"
    done
    cp /etc/resolv.conf "/etc/resolv.conf.pre:$dev"
    cat > /etc/resolv.conf <<END
# generated by /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
$R
END
    ;;
  down)
    mv "/etc/resolv.conf.pre:$dev" /etc/resolv.conf
    ;;
esac
```

Then give the file excute permission:

```
chmod +x /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

Then try to connect again

```
openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

---

NOTE: 
After this configuration I noticed that I can't reach internet without openvpn.

And to fix this open this file

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then remove everything and replace it with any dns you want local dns or google dns ..etc

```
nameserver yourDns
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed OpenVPN from the Ubuntu repo, it should have installed the
file `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` and solution(3) should have worked,
to add the lines:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

And then run:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

If the file was not created, create it manually and paste inside the above lines.